# Hello world code for machine instruction generation at run time?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I sit on Intel MacOSX 10.6 and using GCC 4.2.1 under the hood. What I am attempting to do is to allocate a buffer, populate it with machine instructions, and run it. All in a single program.

For instance,

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    byte_t* code = new byte_t[3];
    code[0] = 0x90; // NOP
    code[1] = 0xC9; // LEAVE - tried also without this.
    code[2] = 0xCB; // RET far - tried also 0xC3, the near return.
    ((void (*)(void)) code)();
    return 0;
}
```

fails with the message *Bus error*. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Some kind of execution prevention. The section of memory that your `code` byte array is in is marked non-executable for security reasons.

Comment: apart from the main issue @unwind mentioned, remove the `LEAVE`, its for cleaning up stack frames and will corrupt `EBP` & `ESP` if you don't have a frame setup, also, you want to use `RETN` (opcode 0xC3) not `RETF`.

Comment: there are a number of self modifying code questions already on StackOverflow, some with working examples.  What you are trying to do here is execute data not code, so the operating system is, naturally, preventing you from doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory is not considered "safe" for code execution, so the operating system prevents it.

Look into using [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) to allocate the memory, and use the `PROT_EXEC` to ask for the memory to be made executable.